# NodeJS rest api with mysql cannot iterate on the output format

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, rest, angularjs-http

Guys I followed a tutorial about how to implement a rest api with node+express+mysql and here is a route from inside my code REST.js file:

```
router.get("/companies",function(req,res){
    var query = "SELECT * FROM ??";
    var table = ["company"];
    query = mysql.format(query,table);
    connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
        if(err) {
            res.json({"Error" : true});
        } else {
            res.json({"Companies" : rows});
        }
    });
});
```

and this is how I call them using angular:

```
sampleApp.controller('InstallController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/companies').
            success(function (data) {
                $scope.clients = data;
            });
}
```

and html

```
  <option ng-repeat="client in clients">{{client}}</option>
```

this is  what I get as a response:

```
    {
  "Companies": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "GOLF"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "RENAULT"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "AUDI"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "MAZDA"
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to iterate on the result to populate a select tag with names. Bear with me please, I'm starting. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use below, but you could only have `id` value inside `selectedClient` when you select any value.

```
<select ng-model="selectedClient">
    <option value="client.id" ng-repeat="client in clients.Companies">
      {{client.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

---

Even better option would be using `ng-options` directive on `select` dropdown, so here you can select object instead of primitive value. Like you will have  `{"id": 1, "name": "GOLF" }` object when you select `GOLF` option, whether as repeating option with `ng-repeat` has limitation to select primitive type value by it.

```
<select ng-model="selectedClient" ng-options="client.name for client in clients.Companies"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you! But I think you meant clients.Companies instead of clients.Clients

Comment: Spot on. Ng-reapeat should be `clients.Companies`. I came across similar issue yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have everything hooked together correctly you just need to change the assignment of $scope.clients.

```
$scope.clients = data.Companies;
```

Then in your HTML

```
<option value="{{client.id}}" ng-repeat="client in clients"> 
   {{client.name}}
</option>
```